# how to update Angular version from 15 to 16?

Tags: angular, npm

I am doing angular version update from 15 to 16.

I uninstalled npm packages and re-installed it with the latest version for the most.

However, angular version still shows "15.1.0".

How to update this in cmd?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzFaQ.png)

Comment: there is a website for this: https://update.angular.io/?v=15.0-16.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the official Angular page for that.
[Link of Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/)

Based on your App you should change the requirements or steps, if you use Angular Material you need to match the option.

1.- Node.js versions: v16 and v18.

2.- TypeScript version 4.9.3 or later.

3.- Zone.js version 0.13.x or later.

If you are using CLI, run the next code

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

Then you need to run the next code, I used the `--force` because didn´t work well.

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli --force
```

Then, run this.

```
ng generate @angular/core:standalone
```

And the last conigurations are in the official page

Comment: on official [page](https://update.angular.io/) this line for some reason is not mentioned `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`

Comment: Thank you! btw I have encountered another complaint - In the pipeline, it shows the version of Node is "16.13.1" and it should be upgraded.. but from "ng version", I can see the version is actually "18.14.0" in cmd.. Any idea?

Comment: DIdn´t work "npm update -g", you can use --force to force it or you can see the node and npm compatibility in this page [link](https://nodejs.org/ro/download/releases).

Comment: @alonso at what point will we be able to move back to just a standard `npm i` without forcing potential issues?

Comment: `ng update @angular/material@16` for material as well.